# Tabs and only tabs for any file type

Tags: vimrc, tab-characters

I would like vim to only ever insert a space character when I touch the space bar.  Instead vim decides that sometimes tabs should be 4 spaces.  How do I force vim to always and forever use tabs regardless of what any other vim config in my system says to do?  No matter what I place in .vimrc it still gives me spaces.

Comment: Uh, vim should by default insert a space when you hit the space bar? I’m confused by your first sentence. That said, you can control the tab settings with `expandtab`, which may be set by ftplugin files.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I tripped over that sentence too. The OP means that they never want a space entered if they *haven't* pressed the space bar. (Not that they don’t want the space bar to insert anything other than a space.)

Answer (score 2):

If I’ve understood you correctly, you want to do something like this in your vimrc:

```
augroup
  au!
  au FileType * setlocal noexpandtab
augroup
```

But I cannot guarantee this works (i.e., something might get triggered after this autocommand that sets `expandtab`). I think you could establish a buffer-local `BufEnter` autocommand inside the `FileType` autocommand, but that will be needless complexity if you never run into a situation where this doesn’t work.

I also cannot really recommend this... for one, I prefer spaces :) but additionally, this is very difficult to override when you *want* spaces!

A *far* better approach is to put `setlocal noexpandtab` in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/{filetype}.vim` anytime you run into a filetype that is using spaces where you want tabs.

Comment: There's also other settings that can cause Vim to insert spaces even under `noet`, for instance if `softtabstop` is set and `&sts < &ts` or if `shiftwidth` is set, `&sw < &ts` and you use the `>` or `<` commands, or indent/dedent with `CTRL-T` or `CTRL-D` or some automatic indentation with `autoindent`... In short, it's not *that* easy to force tab indents everywhere...

Comment: Too true! @filbranden

Comment: noexpandtab is set in both ~/.vimrc and ~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim. When I hit tab on a blank line, I get a tab.  When I hit tab to indent existing text, I get spaces.